# Is there any Online Certification that is worthy enough to get a Job as a Security Professional?

Tags: linux, penetration-test, wifi, kali-linux, certification

I am highly interested in Network and Information Security and already a good understanding of Linux. I am also good at WiFi Penetration Testing and practice a lot of that.

I am wondering that is there a certification that is offered online and has a global reputation so that I don't have to go for exams(that can also be online)?

I am already aware of Cybrary.it, OffensiveSecurity but they don't issue a globally recognized certificate.
Thanks so much

Comment: I got a resource for you. It's a [list of courses with certificates](https://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_messages/1304383). The website is dutch and some of the links don't work, but I think it might be of use to you.

Comment: whether or not something will get you a job depends on who is hiring you -and if OffensiveSecurity is not globally recognised, then your standards are ... interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at GIAC, CompTia and ISC2 certifications. If you are new to security (i.e. don't have 10+ years of experience in it) then starting with the CompTiA Security+ and moving to CEH will provide the credibility to your name.

Currently, the majority of the Information Security job postings require a mixture of certifications, experience and knowledge. If you don't have experience then you would need to compensate with certifications covering the area you are interested in and a lot of knowledge in that area. Side projects help greatly too.

Comment: Are any of those that you mentioned 'online'? I'm certain none of them are.

Comment: Credible and professional certifications tend to have online training but in person exams to ensure authenticity of the taker. [Harvard](https://www.extension.harvard.edu/academics/professional-graduate-certificates/cybersecurity-certificate) and [Stanford](https://www.extension.harvard.edu/academics/professional-graduate-certificates/cybersecurity-certificate) are online and might have some weight.

Answer (score 0):

CEH is a really good certification, however you should have worked 2 years (or more) just to be able to take the exam. CISP is another good one. If you can, take advantage of Cisco Cybersecurity scholarship to obtain Cisco CCNA CyberOps, this one will allow you to work in a SOC. However, in my opinion, it shows you just some theoretical things about security.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are lots of courses with a certification on the internet. But actually, you need to pay for the most of them.

Another thing, I think that you should use Udemy instead of Cybrary. That's what I've done. But it's your own opinion of course. Good luck!

Comment: The OP never stated that he was looking for 'free', only 'online'. Stating that "there are lots" is not very helpful without some direction (I, personally do not know of many that fits the OP's requirements). You also do not provide any guidance on why one should go with Udemy.

Comment: I am respecting that- I'm pointing you to how to improve the answer